# Does T4 up-to-date check handle input file non-existence properly?

Tags: c#, t4

I need a simple T4 template that includes `X.txt` file, if it exists. If `X.txt` is missing -- it should include `X.fallback` (which is always present).

What is the best way to achieve this and keep up-to-date checks working properly in VS?

I.e. suppose `X.txt` is missing and project is already built (i.e. pressing `F7` doesn't do anything). If I create `X.txt` and press `F7` -- template should regenerate output file as part of the build.

Comment: How are you doing the "include"? Are you doing `<#@ include file="" #>` or are you doing `Write( File.ReadAllText( ... ) )`? To my knowledge, T4 does not allow `<#@ include file="" #>`-files to be missing: you get a T4 compilation error, so you'll have to use `if( File.Exists( "x.txt" ) ) Write( File.ReadAllText( "x.txt" ))`, however you _cannot_ use that technique to include compliable C# for the T4 template.

Comment: @Dai I use: `String p = "X"; if (!File.Exists(p)) p = "X.fallback"; Write(File.ReadAllText(p));`. Now, if I build project, delete `X` and run build again -- t4 output is **NOT** regenerated...

Comment: What if you add a `<DependsOn>x.txt</DependsOn>` element to your `.tt` file in your `.csproj`?

Comment: @Dai no effect. `All outputs are up-to-date.` It seems that file opened by `ReadAllText()` doesn't get added to list of dependencies and `DependsOn` has no effect.

Comment: Looks like you need to add a custom `<Target>`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order?view=vs-2022

Comment: @Dai Yeah... looks like I need to employ some very msbuild-specific magic :-/. Problem is that MSbuild treats missing file as `always-outdated` input, meaning project will keep rebuilding unless `X` gets created

Comment: @Dai I need somehow force `up-to-date check` to consider `X` as input only if it exists. And I know there is also completely separate `fast-up-to-date check` in VS...